# Whats the difference between a mode and a harmonic?

Tags: waves

I understand that they two words are interchangeable in a open tube but I cannot understand what the difference is in a half closed tube.

Answer (score 1):

A mode is a property of a system. A certain waveform or pattern that the system can sustain, like a vibration on a guitar string that has 0 amplitude at the points where the string is connected to the body of the guitar. The modes can be defined or described (as properties of the system) whether you pluck the string or not.

A harmonic is a component of a signal. A sinusoidal component of the signal that has a frequency at an integer multiple of the signal's fundamental frequency.

Often the modes of a system will be excited by different harmonics of a stimulus signal. But the modes are properties of the system and the harmonics are components of the signal.