# What is a mode in electromagnetic theory

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, quantum-optics

I am a self learner in quantum opitcs and the books they usually use the words like "single mode" and "multimodes".
My question is what is a mode in electromagnetic theory ?

Comment: Also: [Whats the difference between a mode and a harmonic?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443216/22927)

Comment: If the discussion is about the free-space beams then they could mean [Gaussian modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_beam). Loudon also uses single-mode to denote continuous light beams (no start or end, end therefore single-frequency).

Comment: It is a vocabulary used about optical fibers and the transfer of information using electromagnetic waves, not in the vocabulary of the EM theory :